# How to list all files of a given directory in Mac terminal except a file or directory

Tags: git, bash, macos

I want to display all the files in the working directory except for a file or directory. We have `--exclude` option in Ubuntu for `dir` command.

To be more specific, am trying to move files of my working directory to a subdirectory using this command:

```
git ls-tree -z --name-only HEAD | xargs -0 -I {} git mv {} sub_directory/
```

And, while doing that, I don't want to move few files and directories. How can that be achieved in Mac?

Comment: if you want to move files with certain file or directory excluded, you should use `rsync` command.

Comment: Do you have access to **Perl** and **find**

Answer (score 0):

I am using macOS 10.12.5 . I did these steps:

(1) Install Homebrew

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Reference: https://brew.sh/

(2) Install `tree` command what likes on Linux.

```
brew install tree
```

(3) Use command `tree` and exclude directory pattern (For example: Exclude directory `foo` and `fuu`).

```
tree -f -I "foo|fuu"
```

Learn more: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61078

See official document about command `tree`, on macOS type:

```
tree --help
```

You will see many options, arguments for this command.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response Nhu. The tree command is not working with my git mv. Here is what I've tried:
`tree -f -I v2 | xargs -0 -I {} git mv {} v1/`
Got this error: fatal: 
_bad source, source={}, destination=v1/{}_

Comment: am trying to move contents of currently directory to v1 skipping the contents to v2

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move files with certain file or directory excluded, it is recommended to use `rsync` command. you can also use `git clean` to remove untracked files from the working tree.